# IDA PRO: Monitor variable during execution

Tags: ida, disassembly, debugging, ida-plugin, executable

I'm new with IDA. Say I have a variable which is created in some function and it is argument to other functions.
My question is how to monitor this variable? In monitor I mean is there any way to set some kind of breakpoint and stop execution every time something is written or read from this variable? Or somehow trace the read/write operation on it? thanks.

Comment: What CPU target? Follow up question is whether there is an IDA debugger option for it. I have been looking at similar for a target without an IDA debugger. I have called an instruction set simulator dll from IDA Python, but hit performance problems early on with Python so need to write a plug in.

Comment: @JohnBanks: post your own question, don't hijack others' questions for your issues.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the architecture and the debugger backend selected, you should be able to use a hardware breakpoint to monitor reads and/or writes to a specific memory location. See [Breakpoint Options](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1407.shtml) for more details.